# Query to fetch record based upon a combination of columns and a status column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have a table like this,

```
+----------+----------+-----------+------------+
|       id |    group |      info | status     |
+----------+----------+-----------+------------+
|        1 |        1 | VALUE123  | EXECUTED   |
|        2 |        1 | VALUE123  | INPROGRESS |
|        3 |        1 | VALUE123  | UPLOADED   |
|        4 |        1 | VALUE123  | UPLOADED   |
|        5 |        1 | VALUE123  | UPLOADED   |
|        6 |        1 | VALUE123  | UPLOADED   |
|        7 |        2 | VALUE123  | EXECUTED   |
|        8 |        2 | VALUE123  | UPLOADED   |
|        9 |        2 | VALUE123  | UPLOADED   |
|       11 |        2 | VALUE123  | UPLOADED   |
|       12 |        2 | VALUE123  | UPLOADED   |
|       13 |        2 | VALUE123  | UPLOADED   |
+----------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

I am trying to for a query that should give me a record such that the no row in the table should with the same combination of "group" and "info" would not have status as in "INPROGRESS".

But since I have limited knowledge in forming such complex queries I am not able to make much progress.

For example, the query will be giving me a record from any one of the rows from id [7 - 13] but not from row [1 - 6].

Reason: Since id 2 has its status as 'INPROGRESS', rows [1 - 6] will not satisfy the criteria.

Hope my query makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    wher t1.grp = t.grp and and t1.info = t.info and t1.status = 'INPROGRESS'
)
```

Alternatively, in MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        max(status = 'INPROGRESS') over(partition by grp, info) as flag
    from mytable t
) t
where flag = 0
```

Note: `group` is a language keyword (as in `group by`), hence not a good choice for a column name; I renamed it to `grp` in the queries.

Comment: Thank you so much @GMB. Your query worked for me. I am marking it as solved.